# Tag for tax funded public art/culture patronage?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Do any existing tags apply to tax funded public art or culture, or also government permission to place or maintain these even at private or corporate expense?  Could be applied to things like large monuments, PBS, fireworks, museums, symphonies, or grants.

If not, what might be a good tag name for this general class of things?

Answer (score 2):

I'd think that's too localised. Instead, it'd be better to have a [culture](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) tag and combine with the appropriate tags (i.e. combine with the [tax](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tax) tag in your example).

As for culture, I think the following sentence on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture) gives an idea of its scope:

> The concept of material culture covers the physical expressions of culture, such as technology, architecture and art, whereas the immaterial aspects of culture such as principles of social organization (including practices of political organization and social institutions), mythology, philosophy, literature (both written and oral), and science comprise the intangible cultural heritage of a society.

Comment: Calling the tag "culture" seems much too broad to me. "arts-and-culture" is clunky, but would make it more clear that we're talking about the "arts" definition of culture, rather than the "cultural identity" definition

Comment: @divibisan it depends on how broad you want to make it. If you want to use the tag for questions about UNESCO and heritage then [culture] seems better. If it's only about the arts then it's too narrowly scoped I think (so it will just have a few questions). Also, questions about cultural identity and traditions could benefit from the broader tag.

Comment: It sounded like agc was asking in the more narrow sense, but I could be wrong there.

Comment: @divibisan, The Q. is asking about the narrower sense of governmental support, (whether by commission, grant, endowment, permit, license, or law), for consciously promoted public cultural objects that either wouldn't otherwise exist, or that wouldn't be possible on a large scale without government support of some kind.

Comment: @divibisan, **Example:** a museum exhibit of wigs and hairdos from 200 years of US  Presidents and First Ladies.  **Non-example:** the current hair of the US Senate -- even though all that Senator hair is indirectly paid for by the govt., and it comprises a kind of culture, it's not a conscious attempt at a cultural object, and would exist in any event.